# How can I link a Mamiya 7ii with a Yongnuo YN-560III and suitable Yongnuo RF transmitter?

Tags: yongnuo, mamiya

I own a Mamiya 7ii camera and would like to use a flashgun mounted on stand with an umbrella and trigger it from the camera, manual only. Would the Yongnuo YN-560 III and a suitable Yongnuo transmitter work? If so, what model transmitter?

Note: the hotshoe on the camera only has a single contact.

Answer (score 2):

The YN-560tx transmitter is a perfect match for a YN-560 III flash as it will allow you to control the flash power settings right from the camera.

It comes in both Canon and Nikon versions but should work just fine on your  Mamiya.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly use a YN-560 III off-camera from the Mamiya hotshoe in the way you envision with a Yongnuo transmitter. The single pin of the hotshoe simply means you can't use any TTL options and must go manual only.

The YN-560 III, btw, has two successor models: the [YN-560 IV](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn560-iv-flash-announced/) and announced (but not yet released) [YN-660](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn660-speedlite-announced/).  They both offer a built-in RF master transmitter, as well as a receiver. The Mk IV can control three groups. The YN-660 will control six groups, and has an updated physical UI (dial instead of four-way buttons).  For the stated purpose, here, however, there are no additional advantages to these later models.

The Yongnuo RF triggers that the YN-560 III's built-in receiver can recognize are the RF-602's transmitter unit [RF-600TX], RF-603, [RF-603II](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-rf-603-ii-released/), [RF-605](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-rf605-flash-trigger-announced/), and the dedicated YN-560-TX transmitter.  Of these, the [YN-560-TX](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn560-tx-now-available/) is your best choice, since it's the only one that will let you control the power output level and zoom setting of a YN-560III/IV or YN-660 from the camera.